# What is the best way (as in best practices) to implement a "System User" on the database level?

Tags: database

I'm building an application that imports a lot of its data from another source and so often I'll be writing data to a database table that expects a `user_id` on the row.

Since this data is being imported by the system and not an actual user, a `user_id` isn't necessarily available which brings me to my question. Should I create an actual system user on the users table or should I just allow the `user_id` field to be `nullable` which would indicate that the system imported that row?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should specifically set the userid of whoever/whatever did the import.

It makes it possible to tell the difference between the system user and a failure.

Comment: And technically, the person who did the import *is* the user of record.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the user in this case would be a nightly scheduled cron job.

Comment: FWIW, the job runs as a user also, so you actually can get the userid.